# How to check if the default JS object been modified?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, userscripts, monkeypatching

How can I check from my JS script (running on my HTML page, that is loaded in user's browser), that some base JS API been spoofed by user (browser extension or whatever)? Like `HTMLElement.prototype.appendChild()` method or `screen.width` property?

Comment: How will you check that your check hasn't been modified…?

Comment: You can't. You can't trust the client by any means.

Comment: Why do you want to?

Comment: Interest but it is very hard to find right way for this. Look at react.js they have const type values. ;)  @JonasWilms have a right. What ever you predict all source is exposed when come to the client (browser). Maybe if involve server's for your cheking...I will support this Q

Comment: @jonrsharpe  why would I want to know something? hard to answer

Comment: Well what was the problem you were trying to solve that led to you wanting to check this? Without context, this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @JonasWilms an answer below shows at least two simple cases, when it's possible

Comment: @jonrsharpe I just try to figure out how it works, that's all

Comment: How *what* works? Frankly, pure curiosity tends to lead to bad SO questions for exactly this reason.

Comment: @jonrsharpe just read carefully. I asked "How to check ...", you answered "You can't", but CertainPerformance listed two ways to find monkepatched   fingerprints :)

Comment: @d-d and neither of these solve the problem. They solve *parts* of the problem but aren't a solution in of themselves. This is because jonrsharpe  is correct - you *can't*. There is no conclusive way to do this check.

Comment: @VLAZ I'm not saying that it completely solves the problem, I'm not saying that it's possible (just because I have no proofs) but the solution may consist of many parts that we can find together. If it's still impossible, at least a reason why would be great to know.

Comment: @d-d because the client-side code is completely under control of the user. I'm not even sure that's worth a separate answer, it's the basic tenant of all security. Do not trust the client with anything. Any of your client-side checks can be spoofed. Heck, your code might just get modified to always return `true` or to never run.

Comment: @VLAZ you are right about my code been spoofed, and I should clarify in my initial question, that client doesn't try to do so (dclient doesn't know about this test), and I want to know in this case if I can check base JS objects and find some breadcrumbs that lead me to the conclusion, that something been modified there

Comment: @jonrsharpe sorry, I misunderstood the message

Answer (score 1):

A basic (but by no means foolproof) method would be to check if the function is still composed of native code. If not, then it's *definitely* been monkeypatched; if so, then if it's been monkeypatched, it's also had its `toString` method purposefully changed, to avoid this sort of detection (which is possible, but probably pretty unusual to see):

```js
const checkValid = () => {
  const { appendChild } = Node.prototype;
  if (appendChild.toString() === `function appendChild() { [native code] }`) {
    document.write('Might not have been modified<br>');
  } else {
    document.write('Definitely modified<br>');
  }
};


checkValid();
Node.prototype.appendChild = () => {
  console.log('My monkeypatched function');
};
checkValid();
// Check is foolable via:
const fooler = function appendChild() {
  console.log('My monkeypatched function');
};
fooler.toString = () => `function appendChild() { [native code] }`;
Node.prototype.appendChild = fooler;
checkValid();
```

> Like HTMLElement.prototype.appendChild() method

The object that `appendChild` is directly on is `Node.protoype.` If the monkeypatcher has put it on `HTMLElement.prototype` (or the element itself), that's easily detectable:

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div');
if (HTMLElement.prototype.hasOwnProperty('appendChild')) {
  console.log('Definitely modified');
}

if (div.appendChild !== Node.prototype.appendChild) {
  console.log('Definitely modified');
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: yeah, I thought about this method too, but `toString` can be recursively patched as you mentioned

Comment: In the end, it's the user's own browser - they can run the code they want on it. Even if you code in such a check, they could simply remove the code that does the checking, and run the rest of the code.

Comment: sure, I just try to understand the basics

Comment: It'll be easy to catch lazy monkeypatchers, and impossible to catch expert monkeypatchers.